# Which sport has the most skewed gender ratio among its fanbase?

Tags: trivia, gender, fans

I'm looking for the sport where the male-to-female ratio among its fans is the highest. I can find some statistics for individual sports (e.g. [Statista](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1134065/share-soccer-fans-gender/) says the ratio for soccer fans is about 62%-38%) but not across most sports.

Comment: I have absolutely no evidence whatsoever, but I'm going to guess beach volleyball.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: Really? The guys in beach volleyball don't wear much either.